# Fill missing values with either previous or subsequent values by key

Tags: python, pandas, replace, missing-data

I have this pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
ds1 = {'col1':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2], "col2" : [1,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ds1)
print(df1)

    col1  col2
0      1   1.0
1      1   NaN
2      1   NaN
3      1   NaN
4      1   NaN
5      1   NaN
6      1   NaN
7      2   NaN
8      2   NaN
9      2   NaN
10     2   NaN
11     2   NaN
12     2   NaN
13     2   3.0
```

I need to fill the missing values for `col2` with the non-missing value present in `col1` , for the same value of `col1`.

In this case, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
    col1  col2
0      1   1.0
1      1   1.0
2      1   1.0
3      1   1.0
4      1   1.0
5      1   1.0
6      1   1.0
7      2   3.0
8      2   3.0
9      2   3.0
10     2   3.0
11     2   3.0
12     2   3.0
13     2   3.0
```

Does anyone know how to do it in Python?

Comment: `df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('first')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways of doing this. The simpler approach using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) works if you only have one non-null value per group and you want that as the fill value for all NaNs:

```
df1.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('first')

0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    3.0
13    3.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64

df1['col2'] = df1.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('first')
```

---

Alternatively, `groupby` and forwardfill/backfill per group.

```
(df1.groupby('col1', as_index=False, group_keys=False)['col2']
    .apply(lambda c: c.ffill().bfill()))

0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    3.0
13    3.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

I recommend this option if you have data that looks like this: 1, NaN, NaN, 2, NaN, NaN, 3, NaN, NaN. Because these fill only backfill missing values based on the last non-null value.

The trailing `bfill` call is useful if you have leading NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary that maps col1 values to col2 values:

```
map_col1_to_col2 = df1[['col1', 'col2']].dropna().set_index('col1').to_dict()['col2']
```

Then for all rows where col2 is missing: map col1 using the map_col1_to_col2 dictionary and assign this as col2.

```
df1.loc[df1['col2'].isna(), 'col2'] = df1.loc[df1['col2'].isna(), 'col1'].map(dict_map)
```